# how to get 18 bit code address from symbol defined in linker command file

Tags: linker-scripts, bare-metal, code-composer

In Code Composer, you can define new symbols in the linker command file simply:

```
_Addr_start = 0x5C00;
_AppLength  = 0x4C000;
```

before the memory map and section assignment. This is done in the bootloader example from TI.

You can then refer to the address (as integers) in your c-code as this

```
extern uint32_t _Addr_start; // note that uint32_t is fake. 
extern uint32_t _AppLength;  // there is no uint32_t object allocated

printf("start = %X len= %X\r\n", (uint32_t)&_Addr_start, (uint32_t)&_AppLength);
```

The problem is that if you use the 'small' memory model, the latter symbol (at 0x45C00) gives  linker warning, because it tries to cast it to a 16-bit pointer.

```
"C:/lakata/hardware-platform/CommonSW/otap.c", line 78: warning #17003-D: 
relocation from function "OtapGetExternal_CRC_Calc" to symbol "_AppLength"
overflowed; the 18-bit relocated address 0x3f7fc is too large to encode in
the 16-bit field (type = 'R_MSP_REL16' (161), file = "./otap.obj", offset =
0x00000002, section = ".text:OtapGetExternal_CRC_Calc")
```

I tried using explicit `far` pointers, but code composer doesn't understand the keyword `far`.  I tried to make the dummy symbol a function pointer, to trick the compiler into thinking that dereferencing it would.... The pointer points to code space, and the code space model is "large" while the data space model is "small".

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out before I finished entering the question!

Instead of declaring the symbol as

```
extern uint32_t _AppLength; // pretend it is a dummy data
```

declare it as

```
void _AppLength(void); // pretend it is a dummy function
```

Then the pointer conversion works properly, because `&_AppLength` is assumed to be `far` now. (When it declared as an integer, `&_AppLength` is assumed to be `near` and the linker fails.)